# How to test Markovian property in a financial time series?

Tags: markov-process, finance

I want to build a Markov Chain model for a financial time series to determine transition probabilities from one state to another. The underlying assumption is that series obeys the Markovian property. I believe this is still an open question in the literature whether financial time series (e.g, stock prices, returns) are Markovian or not, and it is indeed impossible to confirm either hypothesis.

What is the acceptable approach/protocol in the literature for testing Markovian property in financial time series? Can AR(p) model or ACF/PACF be useful to draw some conclusions about Markovian property of time series?

(Please give references for books/articles, if any.)